# Is there a way to assign values to individual buttons I've created using root.Button.grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in python/tkinter.

So I drew a 3x3 grid using xxx.Button.grid, now I want to assign properties to each button so I can input text that will determine "X" or "O"

What I would like to do is assign a 1 or a (-1) to the empty square that holds a value of 0, thus determining X's and O's. My hope is that approaching it this way will help me in finding win conditions.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Grid, Button, N, S, E, W


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
frame = Frame(root)

root.title("DJB")

root.minsize(300, 300)
root.resizable(False, False)

root.configure(bg='black')
# --------------------------------------------

Grid.rowconfigure(root, 3, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 3, weight=1)

frame=Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)


for row_index in range(3):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
    for col_index in range(3):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
        btn = Button(frame, bg="white") #create a button inside frame
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

If I can just input code to each button, it would move my project along. Ultimately, I'm making a grid of buttons that when pressed, displays text and toggles an integer between +1 and -1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your button text by `widget["text"]`. Pass this as a command to dynamically retrieve the value:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Grid, Button, N, S, E, W

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
frame = Frame(root)

root.title("DJB")

root.minsize(300, 300)
root.resizable(False, False)

root.configure(bg='black')
# --------------------------------------------

Grid.rowconfigure(root, 3, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 3, weight=1)

frame.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)

def get_value(widget):
    if widget["text"] == "" or widget["text"] == "X":
        widget["text"] = "O"
        #value = 1
    else:
        widget["text"] = "X"
        #value = -1

for row_index in range(3):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
    for col_index in range(3):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
        btn = Button(frame, bg="white",font="Arial 40 bold",width=3)
        btn.config(command=lambda x=btn: get_value(x))
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code, let me know if this helps you.

I added a function that will return a id of the button pressed.

**Function:**

```
# This Function will return Button id 
def button_id(id):
    print("Button {} is pressed".format(id))
    return id
```

**Complete code:**

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Grid, Button, N, S, E, W, mainloop
from functools import partial

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
frame = Frame(root)

root.title("DJB")

root.minsize(300, 300)
root.resizable(False, False)

root.configure(bg='black')
# --------------------------------------------

Grid.rowconfigure(root, 3, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 3, weight=1)

frame=Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)

# This Function will return Button id 
def button_id(id):
    print("Button {} is pressed".format(id))
    return id

id = 1

for row_index in range(3):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
    for col_index in range(3):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
        btn = Button(frame, bg="white", command = partial(button_id, id=id)) #create a button inside frame
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        id += 1

mainloop()
```